# Как узнать есть ли активные стейты в aiogram v3.x

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

Кратко, такая тема. Есть любой активный стейт и есть функция работающая на любой текст

```
user_handler = Router()
@user_handler.message()
```

При передаче данных от пользователя сообщением, то данные не передаются тк они не доходят до обработчика а просто выскакивает главное меню, так сказать.

Была идея поместить импорт роутера с постоянноактивным хендлером в конец, но тогда при передаче данных он все равно будет выводить меню, что не красиво.

Я подумал что можно добавить условие в "@user_handler.message()" чтобы оно воспринимало информацию только тогда, когда нет активных стейтов.

Как я это хотел сделать:

```
@user_handler.message(lambda message: not user_handler.get_current().states, content_types=types.ContentType.ANY)
```

Но проблема в том что в aiogram 3 версии у диспетчера(роутера) нет функции get_current(). Вопрос: как решить?